# Searching Subform

Tags: database, ms-access, search, subform

We have a database set up with a main Client Details form - within this there are several subforms relating to services that clients access.  We cannot search the entirity of the subform fields as it just searches records for the single client due to the link.

What would be the best way to search?  I was thinking maybe have a Search option on the switchboard that when clicked allows the user to select a form and then opens that form on its own.  How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I often add a "subform filter" to many of my forms. It's usually a button that pops up a dialog with a "field to search" drop-down and a text box for the search string. Say you had a parent table [Student] with a related child table [Awards]:

[StudentID] Numeric(Long Integer)
[AwardName] Text(255)

The main Student form could have a subform showing the awards that student had received. If you wanted to filter the Student records to show the recipients of the "Math Prize" then the filter to apply on the [Students] table would be

```
[StudentID] IN (SELECT [StudentID] FROM [Awards] WHERE [AwardName]="Math Prize")
```

For substring searches, to find all recipients of "Athlete of the Week", "Female Athlete of the Year", etc., you could construct a filter string like

```
[StudentID] IN (SELECT [StudentID] FROM [Awards] WHERE [AwardName] LIKE "*athlete*")
```

Comment: hmmm, most of the time the subforms only have one record in them as each client often only accesses a service once. Within the subform there is a Number field that needs to be searched but if the user is not on the record of the client who has this number it will say there are no results - would your solution solve this?

Comment: Yes, that would still work, it would use just a slightly different WHERE clause on the SELECT query in the filter string. Say the Awards table had an additional column [TimesAwarded] and you wanted to filter the Student records to show repeat winners you could say `[StudentID] IN (SELECT [StudentID] FROM [Awards] WHERE [TimesAwarded]>1)`

Comment: ok, thanks! How could I put a 'Search' button on the subform that then pops up asking which field they want to search?

Comment: I usually put my "filter" button on the main form since the filter will be applied to the parent records. The button opens a separate Access form via `DoCmd.OpenForm`. The basic structure of *that* form is described in my answer. When the user clicks the `OK` button the VBA code in its `On Click` event builds the filter string and hands it back to the main form.